# mutually exclusive and independent for two dice problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

i'm working on this problem and I'm not sure if I did it correct

The question is, a random man rolls 2 dice.

- (a)Sum = 5
- (b)first die is 4
- (c)sum = 7
- (d)two dice have same #

So I drew a 6x6 graph for this one and figured out the probability of above events. (4/36,6/36,6/36 and 6/36 respectively)

1. which pairs are mutually exclusive? (So I assume they asked me to answer which pairs cannot occur at the same time. So the only one that doesn't overlapp on my graph is (a)Sum=5.
2. which pairs of those events are independent? (again, I think the answer is (a) because other things overlapp in the middle)

Did i do this problem correctly? if not which part did i got it wrong?? Thank you

Comment: It is hard to tell which pairs are your answers.

Comment: I think for both 1,2 the answer is (a) but I assume it's wrong anyways because they asked for pairs..

Comment: But "(a)" is not a pair of events.  Do you mean (a) paired up with all three other events? By "pair", the question means, for example, (a,b) or (b,d).  For example, (a,d) is mutually exclusive because there is no way you could roll a sum=5 if both dice have the same number.

Comment: im not sure about that.. the only reason why I think the answer is (a) is because (b) is on the center of the line so (b), (c) and (d) overlapp with (b). So (a) is the only independent events from those (b),(c),(d). Is my interpretation wrong?? I don't seem to find pairs that are mutually exclusive and independent. But I'm sure (a) is one of the pairs.

Comment: I added an answer below to get into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take both parts separately.  First, part (1.)

Two events are mutually exclusive if one of the events occurring means the other event cannot occur.  So let's look at all 6 possible combinations of {a,b,c,d}

- {a,b} If you know the sum is 5, could the first die be a 4?
- {a,c} If you know the sum is 5, could the sum be 7?
- {a,d} If you know the sum is 5, could both dice have the same number?
- {b,c} If you know the first die is a 4, could the sum be 7?
- {b,d} If you know the first die is a 4, could both dice have the same number?
- {c,d} If you know the sum is 7, could both dice have the same number?

Alternatively, which pairs of events have no overlaps on your 6x6 table.  To me, it appears there are 3 pairs of events that are mutually exclusive.

For part (2.), you have to look for the pairs of events, where, one of the events occurring affects the probability of the other event happening.

Comment: Yes, you are correct on part 1.  For part 2, a pair can be independent and still overlap.  For example, the probability of the sum being 7 is $\frac{1}{6}$, and the probability of the sum being 7 given that the first die is a 4 is also $\frac{1}{6}$, thus b and c should be independent I believe.  I am not as certain on independence as some of the smart users on this site though.

Comment: for part 1, i got {a,c},{a,d} and {c,d} am I correct? And for part 2, Am I looking for pairs that overlaps with each other?? if so, I got {a,b},{b,c},{b,d}. (sorry about deleting the comments, I had to rethink about what you said)

Comment: the events are not necessarily independent just because they overlap.  You have to look at the probability of the events occurring as well as the probability they occur, given that the other event occurs.  For example, $a$ and $b$ are not independent, because the probability of rolling a sum of 5 is 4/36, but given that the first die is a 4, the probability of rolling a sum of 5 is 1/6

Comment: im a bit confused.. what did u get for part 2?? I think its {a,c} {b,d}  and {c,d}

Comment: I believe that {b,c} and {b,d} are the independent pairs.  $P(c)=\frac{1}{6}$ with or without $b$ being true.  And $P(c)=\frac{1}{6}$ with or without $d$ being true.

Comment: {a,d} can't be independent because if i tell you that the sum is 5, the probability that the two dice have the same number goes from 1/6 to zero.  {c,d} can't be independent because, again, if i tell you the sum of the dice is 7, the probability of {d} goes from 1/6 to zero.

Comment: i see thank you so much!